# Using boost::bind with __fastcall

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder-xe8

I have a function `void __fastcall ClassName::FunctionName()`.

I want to create a boost function pointing to that function, using boost::bind. Is this possible? Writing `boost::bind(&ClassName::FunctionName, this)` gives compile error *"member function must be called or its address taken"*.

A possible workaround is to create a wrapper function, but this is undesirable because it creates useless extra code:

```
void ClassName::FunctionName2(){
    FunctionName();
}
...
boost::bind(&ClassName::FunctionName2, this);
```

Comment: [This](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.implementation.stdcall) seems relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by enabling support for `__fastcall` with a macro:

```
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_ENABLE_FASTCALL
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```

After this, boost::bind syntax works as expected.

This is a non-portable extension, and therefore not enabled by default. [Boost::bind documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.implementation.stdcall).